# Disable Plank icon background

Tags: plank

So whenever an application is used, plank will change it's background to highlight it. Is there a way i can disable that? For an example when i start firefox there is that orange "shadow" behind it.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot to show what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no way to change the icon highlighting from within the Plank Settings or the dock.theme file itself. This could be something that is hard-coded and unchangeable.

But I would recommend copying one of the theme folders and playing around with the configuration in the dock.theme file.

You should be able to find your themes here... ~/.local/share/plank/themes
or in your /usr/share/plank/themes directory.